# Please, I'm using the comparison test for a series?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> can i use the comparison test to decide if the folowing series is divergent?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{n3^n}}{7^n+1}$$
>   my working is as follows
>   $$\frac{{n3^n}}{7^n+1}\lt{\frac{{n3^n}}{7^n}}$$
>   which contains
>   $$\frac{3}{7}$$
>   but this is multiplied by $n$ so can I conclude that the comparison test shows divergence?

Comment: Compare to the derivative of the geometric series instead.

Comment: You could also use the fact that $n\leq 2^n$ for all $n$, and thus compare with $\frac{2^n3^n}{7^n}=\left( \frac{6}{7}\right)^n$, which converges quite easily by the Geometric Series test (if for some reason you didn't want to use Ratio Test or the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also go the low-tech route and compare the series against $(6/7)^n$, since for all $n \ge 1$, we clearly have $$\frac{n 3^n}{7^n+1} < \frac{n 3^n}{7^n} < \frac{2^n 3^n}{7^n} = \left(\tfrac{6}{7}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The comparison test shows convergence because:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}n(\frac{3}{7})^n$$

Is convergent, remember that for $|x|<1$ we have:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}n x^n=x(\frac{1}{1-x})'=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $2$ series whose general terms are: $a_n = \dfrac{n3^n}{7^n+1}, b_n = n\cdot. \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n$. Its clear that $0 < a_n < b_n$, and $\sum b_n$ is convergent by the ratio test as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right| = \frac{3}{7} < 1$, thus $\sum a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents:
$$\frac{n3^n}{7^n+1}\sim_\infty \frac{n3^n}{7^n},$$
which converges by the ratio test.